# Deleting Array then display the whole array

Tags: java, arrays

the primary goal of this program is

--to display all 20 arrays
--prompt the user to input a value to be search
--then the program will search the value, if found,disaplay string "found" and that value will deleted
--then it will display the new set of array
--if not found then display a string "not found"

heres the code...

```
public class Trye {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader x=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int z;
    int num[]={11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,23,34};
    int items=num.length;
    boolean found=false;

    for(int a=0;a<items;a++){
    System.out.print(num[a]+" ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("Enter Value YOu Want to search");
    String search=x.readLine();
    int searchId=Integer.parseInt(search);


    for(z=0;z<items;z++){
        if(num[z]==searchId)
        {
            found=true;
            break;}}

    if(found){
        System.out.println("Found Value! "+searchId);

        for(int c=z;c<items;c++){

            num[c]=num[c+1];        
        items--;
        }

        for(int last=0;last<=items;last++){

            System.out.print(num[last]+" ");
            }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(searchId+" Not found");
    }


    }

}
```

and my question, when i input the number 11,22,33 so on, the numbers are deleted but the last output(displaying arrays after deleting) is only 10 elements (it should be 19 elements).

and if i enter 34(the 20th element) the output become OUtOfbounds: 20

pls help...

Comment: when you say delete do you mean, just don't display it or do you want to create a new array with out that value?

Answer (score 0):

items-- should be outside the for statement. The for should also only go to items - 1.

Comment: this also works for me,,  thaaanks

 why should i put the decrement outside the statement?

Comment: Well, items is the number of items in the array. If you remove one, you only want to decrement it once. If you place it inside the for, it will decrement every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should decrement `items` before your first for loop. Also, your second for loop should be `<`, not `<=`

EDIT: Explanation:

You are currently decrementing `items` inside of your for loop. This causes it to be decremented too many times (up to 10, I guess). The reason to put it before the loop instead of after is simple: inside of your loop, you use `num[c+1]` which, if you are going all the way up to your original `items` of `20`, would cause an index out of bounds error (`c+1` would be `20`).

Your second for loop should be `<` so that you do not print out `num[19]`, which is actually the garbage value at the end of your array.

Comment: thaat works!

 can you explain these for me, so that i can absorp my mistakes.

Comment: Here you go. I added some explanations to my post.